# Liner Progress bar Flutter With Text and Points

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make a User interface similar to that image. If the item is in the processing statement I want to make a thin bar after the processing place.
[image]

I think my question is clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [timeline](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines) package.

for example :

```
Container(
    height: 120,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
    child: Timeline.tileBuilder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      theme: TimelineThemeData(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        connectorTheme: ConnectorThemeData(space: 8.0, thickness: 2.0),
      ),
      builder: TimelineTileBuilder.connected(
        connectionDirection: ConnectionDirection.before,
        itemCount: 4,
        itemExtentBuilder: (_, __) {
          return (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 120) / 4.0;
        },
        oppositeContentsBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container();
        },
        contentsBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
            child: Text(
              _processes[index]
            ),
          );
        },
        indicatorBuilder: (_, index) {    

          if (index <= _processIndex) {
            return DotIndicator(
              size: 30.0,
              color: Colors.green,                
            );
          } else {
            return OutlinedDotIndicator(
              borderWidth: 4.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            );
          }
        },
        connectorBuilder: (_, index, type) {
          if (index > 0) {
            return SolidLineConnector(
                color: Colors.green,
              );
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  )
```